# Gravitational time dilation and power beaming

Tags: gravity, black-holes, time, time-dilation

Consider this thought experiment that kept me awake for far too long last night.

Two spacecraft are located near a black hole, and their relative positions are such that, due to the gravitational time dilation caused by the black hole, time goes by 1.1 times as fast for spacecraft B as for spacecraft A.

Then, spacecraft A starts beaming power to spacecraft B using a 100 kW laser, and after one hour (from its own perspective) it stops. For the sake of the argument, let's ignore any efficiency losses because they're not directly related to the crux of the thought experiment.

Now, from spacecraft A's perspective, it sent power at a constant rate of 100 kW for an hour, for a total energy transmission of **100 kWh**. But, from spacecraft B's perspective, it received power at a constant rate of 100 kW for *an hour and six minutes*, for a total energy transmission of **110 kWh**. Spacecraft B seems to have received an extra 10 kWh for free.

Here's the apparent paradox I can't seem to solve:

1. if we accept those extra 10 kWh are real, it breaks the law of conservation of energy, which basically states you can't pull energy out of a hat; but
2. if we reject those extra 10 kWh, it breaks the law of relativity, because we're saying that a time-dependent phenomenon such as the transmission of power at a constant rate is not relative after all.

What gives? What am I missing here? Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the laser beam to consist of a stream of photons emitted at a certain rate. The gap between each photon emission has one value according to ship A and another according to ship B because of the relative time dilation.

So yes, ship B receives the photons for a longer period of time, but it receives them at a lower rate. The overall number of photons would be conserved.

However, the photons are gravitationally redshifted and so individually have lower energy. Thus the total energy received by ship B is lower (according to them) than emitted by ship A.

No energy is lost from the system, since if ship B held up a perfectly reflective mirror, then ship A would receive back 100 kW for an hour (in their frame) - since there is both a blueshift and the reverse of the time dilation as the photons travel back to A.

Comment: Good answer (+1), presumably the redshifted photons, after reflection, become blue-shifted and would arrive back at A with the original energy.  Would they all  be received over the duration of an hour (from the first one arriving back, to the last)?

Comment: @JohnHunter the whole thing is reversed. They are reflected over the course of 1h6m (according to B), but received over an hour by A with the original photon energies because they are blueshifted as they "fall" back towards smaller $r$.

Comment: It seems clear enough that the energy of each photon goes back to the original, as seen by A upon arrival back at A.  It's the hour duration (when received back at A) that is puzzling - does A also observe them to arrive at B over the duration of an hour? perhaps due to the 1hr 6 mins time being reduced back to an hour due to time dilation (reversed)?

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, thanks

Comment: @JohnHunter edited to make this explicitly clear.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer.

Comment: @safesphere I agree that the concept of potential energy cannot be used here. My intention was merely to indicate that the *apparent* loss of energy can be reversed.